# Flutter Error: Expected a value of type 'FutureOr<List<dynamic>>', but got one of type '_JsonMap'

Tags: json, flutter

When I try to decode JSON I get this error:

> Expected a value of type 'FutureOr<List>', but got one of type '_JsonMap'

This is my code for getting the data from the API:

```
Future<List> getData() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final key = 'token';
    final value = prefs.get(key) ?? 0;

    String myUrl = "$serverUrl/userchecks";
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(myUrl), headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $value'
    });

    print('Response status : ${response.statusCode}');

    return json.decode(response.body);
  }
```

Comment: share your JSON response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your returned value from JSON is not a List but it is a JSON map, so you have to change the Future return type like this:

```
Future<Map<String,dynamic>> getData() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final key = 'token';
    final value = prefs.get(key) ?? 0;

    String myUrl = "$serverUrl/userchecks";
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(myUrl), headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $value'
    });

    print('Response status : ${response.statusCode}');

    return json.decode(response.body);
  }
```

or you can do it as it is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67163513/expected-a-value-of-type-listdynamic-but-got-one-of-type-jsonmap).